# Convex constraint in a Mixed-Integer Program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I have an optimization with the following convex constraint:

\begin{equation*}
x_1^2+x_2^2\leq \textrm{C}_1\cdot x_3 + \textrm{C}_2\\
\end{equation*}

My problem also contains some integer variables ($x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ are however continuous).

I know that there are efficient solvers for Mixed-Integer Second Order Cone Programs. Could you help me understand if my constraint is conic quadratic representable, so that I could implement it in an MISOCP? If not, any advice on how I could implement this constraint in a Mixed-Integer Program that can be solved efficiently with available solvers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, from the generic  $x^TR^TRx \leq c^Tc+b$ being SOCP representable as  $\left|\left|\begin{matrix}2Rx\\1-(c^Tx+b)\end{matrix}\right|\right|\leq 1+c^Tx+b$

Comment: don't be so humble, luisba obviously needs YALMIP :)

Comment: Thanks Johan! Do you have any reference where I can read about this?

Comment: Basically any text on second-order cone programming, such as Applications of second-order cone programming by Lobo et. al